# F# - How to call Moq ReturnsAsync()?

Tags: f#, moq

I have a function that returns `Task<bool>` (C#).

```
Task<bool> Update(MemberMarketUpdate memberMarketUpdate);
```

I'm trying to mock it using Moq (F#).

```
let verifyUpdate(update:MemberMarketUpdate) =
    update.Id |> should equal "market id"

let setup = associationRepository.Setup (fun r -> r.Update(It.IsAny<MemberMarketUpdate>() ))
setup.Callback(fun update -> verifyUpdate update) |> ignore
//setup.Returns(Task.FromResult(True)) <- does not compile
//setup.ReturnsAsync(True)  <- does not compile
```

I'm not able to use `ReturnsAsync(True)` to mock the `Task<bool>` result.

The error says:

> No overloads match for method ReturnsAsync. The available overloads
>   are shown below.
>   (35 overloads here)

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to get your code to type check in a simple F# script file and the only thing I had to do to make it work was to change your upper-case `True` to lower-case `true`.

My complete script that type-checks fine, including all the necessary definitions and references looks like this:

```
#r @"packages\Moq\lib\net45\Moq.dll"
#r @"packages\NUnit\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll"
#r @"packages\FsUnit\lib\net46\FsUnit.NUnit.dll"
#r @"packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
open Moq
open FsUnit
open System.Threading.Tasks

type MemberMarketUpdate = 
  { Id: string }

type IAssociationRepository = 
  abstract Update : MemberMarketUpdate -> Task<bool>

let verifyUpdate(update:MemberMarketUpdate) =
    update.Id |> should equal "market id"

let associationRepository = new Mock<IAssociationRepository>();
let setup = associationRepository.Setup (fun r -> r.Update(It.IsAny<MemberMarketUpdate>() ))
setup.Callback(fun update -> verifyUpdate update) |> ignore
setup.Returns(Task.FromResult(true))
setup.ReturnsAsync(true)
```

Comment: aaarrgg. Many thanks Tomas to find out this and the extra tips.
I want to replace Moq with Foq to change setup/callback in something more F# -style, but this is the first step moving away from something I know well like Moq.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with f# but try it all in one fluent call like the following, if possible.

```
associationRepository
    .Setup(fun r -> r.Update(It.IsAny<MemberMarketUpdate>()))
    .Callback(fun update -> verifyUpdate update)
    .ReturnsAsync(True) |> ignore
```

Comment: It gives me the same error as with my non-fluent version.
(Indeed I splitted the fluent in more steps to isolate the error)